# Intershop: Is there a pipeline I can call from the browser to clear the session?

Tags: intershop

I need to provide the user with a way to start over.  I'd like to clear the  secured session cookie with a pipeline call but have found nothing in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the default pipeline - ViewUserAccount-LogoutUser.
That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I tried that once to reset a site session while the user logs out. The easiest way was to set the cookies in delete mode:

```
sid
pgid-[site]
SecureSessionID-[ID]
AuthenticationStateToken-[ID]
```

You can use the SetCookie-Pipelet for this. No custom-code is required.

Don't forget about all the other cookies your site sets: wishlist, cart, user, ... They might pull things into the new session you don't want to have.